# Calculation of principal when rate of interest is increased by a certain percentage

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is about how we interpret the statement "rate of
 interest is increased by 25%". See the below question.

> A sum of money amounts to Rs.944 in 3 years at a simple interest. If
>   the rate of interest is increased by 25% , the sum amounts to 980
>    during the same period. What is the sum?
>
> Answer: Sum is 800
>
> [Source - book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=uoMjCjMyzjUC&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=A%20sum%20of%20money%20amounts%20to%20Rs.944%20in%203%20years%20at%20a%20simple%20interest.&source=bl&ots=PvY5pjLxNH&sig=olE3lRmcyldfcpJwHVTi-jjHJOE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjipJn82_3MAhXJuo8KHdMdD38Q6AEIPTAJ#v=onepage&q=A%20sum%20of%20money%20amounts%20to%20Rs.944%20in%203%20years%20at%20a%20simple%20interest.&f=false)

As per the logic given in the book,

Initial rate of interest = 6%.

initial interest $=\dfrac{800×6×3}{100}=144$

So, amount becomes, $800+144=944$ after 3 years

final interest rate $=6×\dfrac{125}{100}=7.5$

final interest $=\dfrac{800×7.5×3}{100}=180$

So, amount becomes, $800+180=980$ after 3 years

> But, I cannot agree with this answer. According to me, if initial rate
>   of interest is $6\%$, new rate of interest must be $31\%$ due to
>   $25\%$ increment.
>
> But, in the book, new rate of interest is taken as $7.5\%$
>
> I am sorry, if this question is not suitable for this forum as it is
>   how we  interpret the statement. Since, it is mathematical, I am
>   posting it here to get clarity. Please help

Comment: The book appears to mean that the increment is 25% or one-quarter of the 6% interest rate, or 0.25 · 6% = 1.5%  .  So the second interest rate is 6 + 1.5 = 7.5% .  (It does not mean that the interest is being increased by 25 _percentage points_ to 31%.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you miss that $$6/100+25/100\cdot6/100=7.5/100=7.5\%$$

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two notions :

- the book considers a relative increase equal to 25% of 6%, i.e. 2%, leading to 8%. This is the result of $1.25 \cdot 6 = 7.5 $.
- You consider an absolute increase equal to 25 points, leading to $25 + 6 = 31$.

Comment: the book takes new interest as 7.5%, not as 8%.

Comment: Sorry, mistake corrected.